# Добавить отсутствующие в словаре даты

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Есть словарь вида `{<дата>: <значение>}`. В нем находятся даты и нужно найти отсутствующие даты и добавить их с значением 0.

---

Пример словаря:

> {'23/07/2018': '178', '02/08/2018': '90', '01/08/2018': '113',
>   '30/07/2018': '80', '27/07/2018': '107', '26/07/2018': '87'}

Пример функции для тестирования:

```
import datetime as DT

def get_day_by_value():
    d = {
        '23/07/2018': '178','02/08/2018': '90', '01/08/2018': '113',
        '30/07/2018': '80', '27/07/2018': '107', '26/07/2018': '87',
    }

    return {DT.datetime.strptime(k, '%d/%m/%Y'): v for k, v in d.items()}
```

Нужно добавить отсутствующие даты и вывести.

Пример результата:

```
23/07/2018 : 178
24/07/2018 : 0
25/07/2018 : 0
26/07/2018 : 87
27/07/2018 : 107
28/07/2018 : 0
29/07/2018 : 0
30/07/2018 : 80
31/07/2018 : 0
01/08/2018 : 113
02/08/2018 : 90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime as DT

def generate_range_dates(start_date, end_date) -> list:
    date_1 = min(start_date, end_date)
    date_2 = max(start_date, end_date)

    # Сразу добавляем стартовую дату
    items = [date_1]

    while date_1 < date_2:
        date_1 += DT.timedelta(days=1)
        items.append(date_1)

    return items

# Получаем словарь дат
day_by_rep = get_day_by_value()

# Получаем минимальную и максимальную дату из ключей словаря
start_date, end_date = min(day_by_rep), max(day_by_rep)

# Сгенерируем диапазон дат
dates = generate_range_dates(start_date, end_date)

# Пройдемся по диапазону дат
for day in dates:
    print('{:%d/%m/%Y} : {}'.format(day, day_by_rep.get(day, 0)))
```

Результат:

```
23/07/2018 : 178
24/07/2018 : 0
25/07/2018 : 0
26/07/2018 : 87
27/07/2018 : 107
28/07/2018 : 0
29/07/2018 : 0
30/07/2018 : 80
31/07/2018 : 0
01/08/2018 : 113
02/08/2018 : 90
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение с использованием Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    '23/07/2018': '178', '02/08/2018': '90', '01/08/2018': '113',
    '30/07/2018': '80', '27/07/2018': '107', '26/07/2018': '87'
}

s = pd.Series(data)

# cast strings to dates in the index
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index, dayfirst=True)

# fill gaps in the index
s = (s.reindex(pd.date_range(s.index.min(), s.index.max()))
      .fillna(0)
      .astype('int16'))

# cast dates back to string in the index
s.index = s.index.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

# export Series as a dict
res = s.to_dict()
print(res)
```

Результат:

```
In [235]: res
Out[235]:
{'23/07/2018': 178,
 '24/07/2018': 0,
 '25/07/2018': 0,
 '26/07/2018': 87,
 '27/07/2018': 107,
 '28/07/2018': 0,
 '29/07/2018': 0,
 '30/07/2018': 80,
 '31/07/2018': 0,
 '01/08/2018': 113,
 '02/08/2018': 90}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

d = {
    '23/07/2018': '178', '02/08/2018': '90', '01/08/2018': '113',
    '30/07/2018': '80', '27/07/2018': '107', '26/07/2018': '87'
}

ts = sorted(map(lambda x: int(dt.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y').timestamp()), d))
for x in range(ts[0], ts[-1] + 86400, 86400):
    df = dt.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    if df not in d:
        d[df] = '0'

print(d)

# Результат
for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: dt.strptime(x[0], '%d/%m/%Y')):
    print(k, v, sep=' : ')
```

Comment: Итерация словаря возвращает ключи и при работе с оператором `in` обращение тоже идет к ключам, поэтому можно не указывать явно. Решение у вас интересное, но немного сложное